# How do I set a group parameter of Vector Drawable programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector drawable that I want to rotate depending on some input in my app.

I have a vector_drawable.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">

    <group
      android:name="rotation_group"
      android:pivotX="50"
      android:pivotY="50"
      android:rotation="180" >
      <path
          android:pathData="..."
          android:fillColor="#ffffff"/>
      <path
          android:pathData="..."
          android:fillColor="#ffffff"/>
    </group>

    <path
        android:pathData="..."
        android:fillColor="#242424"/>
</vector>
```

In my code, I create a ValueAnimator

```
ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myDrawable, "rotate", 0, 360);
animator.setDuration(500);
animator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);
animator.start();
```

With animatorUpdateListener being defined as follows:

```
animatorUpdateListener = new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
    int angle = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("rotate");
    myAngle = angle;
    myView.invalidate();
  }
};
```

In my onDraw method I then call

```
canvase.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(myAngle);
myDrawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

How would I be able, instead of rotating the canvas, to change the `android:rotation` parameter inside the `rotation_group` of my vector_drawable.xml?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There's no way to alter the XML source definition on the fly.  [`AnimatedVectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) can effectively alter the `android:rotation` parameter, but only to predefined values it seems, not programmatically.

An alternative solution is to rotate the `Canvas` when drawing it, as you currently do.

Or maybe wrap your `VectorDrawable` in a [`RotateDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html) and draw that instead.

Or [`setRotation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) on the whole view.